# Angular data binding to table, possibly with jQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to two-way data bind (I think) to a table, so it will update the index when I sort it - I am currently using jQuery sortable to do this. I am open to other options, of course.

I am using [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/SSSUUUSSS/Bsusr/1/), which seems to be very old. So I am attempting something similar, because this is desired effect. The big difference would be that I am using jQuery UI instead of the angular-ui deal (maybe this is why it does not work correctly). But based on the Fiddle here is my basic setup:

```
<form id="lessonInstructionPlan" class="lessonItem" ng-controller="instructionController">
    <div class="small-12 columns ">
        <div class="saInstPlanHead">
            <h5>Instructional Plan</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="lessonSASlider">
        <div class="row rowFix">

        <div class="small-12 columns text-right saInstrcutionTableCover">
            <div class="row rowFix">
                <div class="small-12 columns lessonItemHeader">
                    <h3>Manage</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row rowFix">
                <div class="hide-for-small medium-12 columns smallCover">
                <!-- Medium -large table -->
                <table class="saInstrcutionTable" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th><th></th><th>Sub Level</th><th>Targets</th><th>Instructions</th><th>Response</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="sortEmPls" ng-model="listTable">

                        <tr ng-repeat="item in listTable">
                            <td class="moveTableLevel"><div class="saTableUp"></div><div class="saTableDown"></div></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>1. {{ $index }} </td><td>{{item}}</td><td>{{item}}</td><td>{{item}}</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>    
                <!-- End Medium -large table -->
```

(There is another table for mobile under this that is being cut off for time's sake).

Here's a snip of my controller (just giving the hard-coded data like from the example)

```
.controller('instructionController', function($scope){

     $scope.listTable = ["one", "two", "thre", "four", "five", "six"];

 })
```

And I'm just calling jQuery sortable on `.sortEmPlease`, which is the table body. It works fine, but it doesn't seem to two-way data bind and update the index based on position.

Comment: I would like to recommend you one small thing. Never try jquery ui with angularjs. Still if you want to use jquery uo than you will have to manage it by creating directives.
The reason directives are needed for this is do to how the DOM is replaced when the routes change. It replaces the DOM with what is cached directly from the server, not the rendered version of what was removed when the route was last viewed. This means that each time the route changes you will need to run the jQuery UI functions to init the jQuery UI widgets.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I am just messing around with options currently but I need to have some sort of way to move the table rows up and down, and it would be nice if they updated their numbers based on their index.

Comment: I would recommend you to write a custom filter in angularjs and write whatever stuff you want to do there :)